# Why does creating multiple directories in R using file.create cause invalid 'path' argument in Windows

Tags: r, windows, directory-structure

I have this simple example how I want to create multiple folders from a character vector in R:

```
folder <- c("test","names","for","rep","example")
list_of_paths <- paste("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/TEST123/",folder, sep="")
dir.create(list_of_paths)
```

It results in an error, which I could not resolve, saying `Error in dir.create(list_of_paths) : invalid 'path' argument`

However when I use a single string like

```
dir.create("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/TEST123/test")
```

it works. I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction here or show me the reason for the error. Thank you and have a good evening,

Konrad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `?dir.create`

> path - a character vector containing a single path name.

So, we may need to loop

```
sapply(list_of_paths, dir.create)
```

Comment: Gosh. So Simple. I was reading vector and wasn´t thinking a vector could only have a single value. Also in `?dir.create` create an argument "paths" for multiple paths is mentioned, but can only be used in `dir.exists` and `Sys.chmod`

Comment: @KonradBauer the documentation shows different functions and its usages.  The `paths` is an argument for `dir.exists` and `Sys.chmod` as you stated.  It is easier to miss as these arguments are only different in the suffix 's'